# Sparing the CPU when wait() is not available

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait

My component integrates to a third-party component. I have to override the `onTick()` method which is called by a high-priority `Thread` of the third-party component. Sample code:

```
@Override
public void onTick() {

    // do many useful operations

}
```

In certain scenarios, this `onTick()` method should not perform those "many useful operations", because their results are discarded. In fact, the functionality of `onTick()` is not needed at all in that case, but the third-party component does not offer any "pause" or "sleep" functionality. It calls `onTick()` **all the time**. This means that CPU time is used up unnecessarily in these special periods.

The most straightforward solution would be to send a signal to `onTick()` and make its thread sleep via an `Object.wait()` in a proper `synchronized` block. However, the documentation of the third-party component states that its `Thread` should not be sent to waiting state arbitrarily.

Is there any solution to save CPU resources in this case? That is, to let others use the CPU? I created the following solution, but I'm not sure it allows to save any CPU. (Nonetheless, at least, it should save other resources used by the "useful operations" section of `onTick()`).

```
@Override
public void onTick() {

        // mJustUnpaused is volatile. Race condition, but probably harmless (?)
        if (mJustUnpaused) { 
            mJustUnpaused = false;
            // THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY is the original 
            // priority used by the 3rd party Thread
            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
        }

        if (!mRunningAllowed) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPauseRequested) { // mPauseRequested is declared as volatile
            synchronized (mPauseLock) {                 
                if (mRunningAllowed && mPauseRequested) {                       
                    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                    mRunningAllowed = false;
                    mPauseLock.notify();
                }
            }               
            return;
        }

        // do many useful operations
}
```

The methods for pausing/unpausing (the first one is blocking, the second isn't):

```
public void pauseWork() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        if (mRunningAllowed && !mPauseRequested) {
            mPauseRequested = true;
            while (mRunningAllowed) {
                try {
                    mPauseLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("RPT", "Already paused or pausing");
        }
    }
}

public void unpauseWork() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        if (!mRunningAllowed) {
            mRunningAllowed = true;
            mPauseRequested = false;
            mJustUnpaused = true;
        } else {
            Log.d("RPT", "No need to unpause");
        }
    }
}
```

Three questions:

1. Is there a better way to save some CPU time?
2. Regardless of everything else, is my above code correct (in terms of synchronization and other programming aspects)?
3. Slightly off-topic, but I don't think it deserves a dedicated question: does changing a Thread's priority have any significant overhead? Are there any general guidelines when such an act can be done? (e.g. how often can it be done, etc.)

Comment: Sleeping a tick type method is probably not something you want to do, unless it is called from a thread which has no other purpose (and even then it might break something).  Unless you can request that the calls stop happening, likely your best bet is to just put the body of the method inside an if() {} block.

Comment: Yeah, the lack of a "pause" method is a huge drawback of the third-party component. I wouldn't like to use this component, but the customer insists on it. Sometimes the onTick() functionality is useless even for 10 seconds, that is why I thought that CPU time could be saved somehow during such a period.

Comment: Why don't you just start the `onTick()` method with `if (nothingToDo() { return; }`?

Comment: As you can see, I'm using mRunningAllowed for the same purpose. But I want to change the thread priority as well, and in case of pausing, I want to wait until the pause completes.

Comment: "but the customer insists on it" -- the customer should find an Android-aware replacement, since it does not sound like this library is designed for use with Android. That being said, how frequently is this `onTick()` called?

Comment: Approximately 30 times per second.

Comment: @ThomasCalc Just returning from the `onTick()` should be enough. Even smartphones can handle calling an empty method that often without much of a performance impact. Now, what I'd avoid is having more of those ticker threads running; if that's the case, maybe you could combine the tick handlers somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to save some CPU time?

I wouldn't even bother with what's there. I agree with Chris Stratton: just avoid doing the actual work, and delete the rest of the other code shown above. Then, use Traceview to see whether or not the overhead of your do-nothing `onTick()` calls is noticeable. Most likely, it will not be.

> But I want to change the thread priority as well

That's not a good idea, as it is not your thread, if I understand the scenario properly. Moreover, I believe that you are going to be called ~300 times regardless, as if the library is coded to call you ~30 times a second, it is likely using a `Timer` or something else that should be relatively immune to thread priority.

> Regardless of everything else, is my above code correct (in terms of synchronization and other programming aspects)?

Personally, I'd use stuff from `java.util.concurrent` and `java.util.concurrent.atomic`, rather than low-level `wait()`/`notify()`/`volatile`. Doug Lea is smarter than I am. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll change to simple boolean checking then. Nonetheless, I'd like to know if my code is correct (i.e. it does what I wrote it does: first method blocks, second doesn't, and there are no unsafe conditions), just to practice/understand to use these low-level concepts. So I'd mark your post as answer, but I'm waiting for an answer which answers my second question as well (whether my code is correct). I'll use java concurrent packages for the next similar task, though.

Comment: @ThomasCalc: "does changing a Thread's priority have any significant overhead?" -- the actual call to `setThreadPriority()` should be fairly cheap AFAIK. "Are there any general guidelines when such an act can be done? (e.g. how often can it be done, etc.)" -- changing it more than once per thread is a code smell IMHO. Set up the thread with the right priority in the first place (and if it is not your thread, leave it alone).